# Combine WMI Query into one line

Tags: c#, wmi

I was looking to detect using WMI events, when a user or a usergroup is modified in local users and groups.Below are 2 queries that work. How can i combine them into one query ? I tried an `or` operand but WMI code creator throws an invalid query exception.

**Working Detect usergroup modification**

```
"SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group'"
```

**Working Detect user modification**

```
"SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_GroupUser'"
```

**Not Working - This is what i tried**

```
"SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group' or SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_GroupUser'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1
WHERE (TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_GroupUser')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I think the parens are needed):

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 
WHERE (TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Group' OR TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_GroupUser')
```